# References for rendering 2-dimensional elements (circle, rounded rectangles, blurry ~)

Tags: c++, python, user-interface, rendering, 2d

I'm writing a Python-module which should provide an easy OOP interface to low-level GUI platforms. To achieve this, a wrapper class needs to be created that is used by the classes in the module.

This is the *(yet)* class-diagram for the basic implementation.

[image: class diagram]

*This question is actually not about the design of the package, but if you have questions to it or have an idea what might be better, I won't mind any comments/critics.*

The *DrawArea* class is the glue between the low-level platform and the classes in the package. Events usually start here, as the wrapper should recognize mouse-/keyboard-events and inform it's children about it.

Now, as you can see, the *DrawArea* class needs to implement some functions to render basic elements onto the GUI. Now, I'd like to get to know about the magic behind rendering circles, rounded rectangles, lines (with a thickness) and about anti-aliasing. One reason for it is that I'm simply interested into that topic, the other is that I'd like to deliver an implementation with the package. (Will be written in C/C++, I'm pretty sure Python would be tot slow for such rendering operations, isn't it?)

**Now my questions**:

1. Are there any good references for how to render circles, ellipses, rounded rectangles, or lines (with a thickness, the *one-pixel-line* is easy..)?
2. Are there any good references for how to implement anti-aliasing?

   - E.g., is anti-aliasing done while rendering an element or applied after all rendering-operations have been done?
3. Would it be better to use something like a `Path` class that will be rendered? I.e. a vectorized representation of the form that should be rendered. That would have the advantage to render any kind of 2-dimensional forms, but I don't know how to implement it. Are there good references for rendering vector-graphics?

Comment: This is beside the point, but may I ask what you used to make that nice class diagram?

Comment: @voithos [gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) :)

Comment: You can take Qt 4 source code and tear it apart to see how it works. It includes renderer with antialiasing support. Or you could take pen+paper and figure out formulas yourself - for antialiased pixel you need to calculate how much of that pixel is covered by primitive you draw. On other hand since there's already Qt and it has python bindings(PyQt), you might end up reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @SigTerm Diggin through source-code isn't the one of the yellow, but a starting point. I actually haven't thought about Qt when thinking of anti-aliasing. I'm not aiming for creating a poor clone of Qt. My aim is to enable highly-dynamic and customizeable user interfaces that are not bound to the operating-systems style. Still "kinda" low-level, but object-orientaded instead of linear rendering. I've already done prototypes of this module, but I'm not convinced about the design. Additionally, more futures (like AA) should be added. (See [this video](http://www.screenr.com/m16s) of a prev. Ver.

Comment: @Niklas R: "highly-dynamic and customizeable user interfaces that are not bound to the operating-systems style." How is that different from what Qt offers (have you seen "qtdemo"?)? Also, keep in mind that development/maintenance of such system will eat a lot of your time - possibly years.

Comment: @SigTerm: I wasn't aware that Qt offers that customizeability. Anyway, Qt is not exactly what I want to do. For example, [Cinema 4D](http://maxon.de) is a 3D Software that provides a class for rendering stuff linearly (not OOP) on a given region. Qt could be implemented with a work-around here, but it cannot be synchronized with the native GUI this software uses. I.e. that class for rendering onto can be combined with predefined GUI elements in a dialog, etc. Difficult to explain to "outsiders"of the C4d dev-community, sorry. (; Anyway, even if I'm reinventing, it's still a good practice.

Comment: @NiklasR You are asking three hard questions at the same time. Question 1 is non-trivial and certainly question 2 (anti aliasing) is a big topic on its own. It's hard to answer such question comprehensively.

Comment: @MarcinK Well, I'm asking for references, not that somebody explains it to me. I mean, there must be a possibility for someone uninvolved to get the knowledge needed for this, doesn't it? I can't imagine all the software-developers out there that have built render-engines or graphics-software did all explore it on their own, did they? I would also accept suggesting me a book or similiar. :) Thanks

Comment: @NiklasR As You asked for references, I added a few more. I hope you like them, and that will help you on "boostrap"/"starting point" :).  Making drawing in 2D can be a really good fun. I've benn programming games on times of 386 486 and then C/assembly optimizations where a must and challenging fun :). Take time to write a few "toy examples" for your self drawing lines, circles. Be careful about corner cases. Ones you fill more fluent will all 2D rendering techniques, start building app.

Comment: Thanks for the references, they're great. I haven't crossed the name of *André LaMothe* yet, and I really ask myself, why? Great stuff, I read an excerpt from the book and I think I'm going to buy it. Also, I always appreciate comments and suggestions from experienced programmers, thanks!

Comment: Remember of awarding best answer with bounty manually, cause automatically points will fly away or just half of points will be given : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Anti-Grain Geometry - High Fidelity 2D Graphics - A High Quality Rendering Engine for C++](http://www.antigrain.com/) is a **programming library**, which is my favourite choice for rendering vector graphics.

You might like to make a **wrapper** of it (take a look at [documentation](http://www.antigrain.com/doc/index.html) ), look into **sources** or ...

[Jump to **Research** section](http://www.antigrain.com/research/index.html) where you can find a lot of information how to do : "High Fidelity 2D Graphics - A High Quality Rendering". Brazier lines and other topics are mentioned there. My favourite section is ["Texts Rasterization Exposures"](http://www.antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/index.html) about sub-pixel rendering.

If you are interested how to optimize drawing lines, polygons etc even on C+assembly level,

- I **encourage** to take look into old but great **book** (showing tricks needed on times of i386): [Tricks of the Game-Programming Gurus by Andre Lamothe, John Ratcliff, Denise Tyler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672305070)
- IF you want more, another book : *"Introduction to Computer Graphics
  James D. Foley, Andries van Dam, Steven K. Feiner, John F. Hughes, Richard L. Phillips"* [ref1](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Introduction-to-Computer-Graphics/9780201609219.page) [ref2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201609215)

Here as example of one of many 2D Computer Graphics algorithms:

- [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) which is widely used cause it only uses integer addition, subtraction, bit shifting - which are fastest instructions to execute
- A lot of modifications, including multicore : [Google Scholar: Bresenham's line algorithm](http://scholar.google.pl/scholar?q=Bresenham%27s+line+algorithm)
- Clear and readable examples how to apply Bresenham to lines, circles etc. : [The Beauty of Bresenham's Algorithm](http://free.pages.at/easyfilter/bresenham.html)
- [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) is classic example of how to draw circle
- But if you'd like to have antialiasing build-in into drawing algorithm (instead of oversampling) you might like to checkout: [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm)
- [Good place to start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_graphics_algorithms) reading about algorithms on net, but really I encourage to look into [Tricks of the Game-Programming Gurus by Andre Lamothe, John Ratcliff, Denise Tyler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672305070)

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful answer, Grzegorz. So much useful information and references. That's what I searched for! You made my day. ;) Just in case, you will receive the bounty when it's about to expire. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it help and you have fun implementing this stuff :).